# UDP python to c - packed binary data - struct.pack('<ff',

Tags: python, c, udp, pack, unpack

client (python):

```
theta = math.sin(23/3) / 300
y = math.cos(23/11) / 20
data=struct.pack('<ff',theta,y) # pack with two float
s.sendto(data, (ip, 50000))
```

server (python):

```
 daten, addr = s.recvfrom(1024) #
 d=struct.unpack('<ff',daten)
 print ("[%s] %s" % (d[0],d[1]))
```

--> works

how can i make a c-file as client??? this in c (data=struct.pack('

client ( c):

```
 ??
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be equivalent to

```
struct {
  float d[2];
};
```

in C (assuming a little-endian host).

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
float value[2];
value[0]=1.22;
value[1]=-2.22;
...
sendto(s,value,sizeof(value),....)
```

thanks